# How to change participant role in CiviRules with trigger "event participant is added"?

Tags: civirules

Is it possible in CiviRules to **change the participant role** (action)
when a **participant is added** (trigger)
for **specific status** (condition)?
The opposite – to update the participant status for certain role(s) using the same trigger – is possible out of the box.
[image]

**Can this be achieved without having to write a new/custom action as described [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-action/)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**By default, CiviCRM uses the default participant role specified in the event settings.** 
As there is only one participant role defined per event in CiviEvent, the desired behaviour can't be achieved through CiviRules.
When doing a **batch import of participants**, the role(s) can be set in the .csv-file.
When **manually registering participants**, one or multiple roles can be chosen.
When **participants register**, an extension like [**THIS**](https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-registration-based-participant-roles) would be necessary in order to have their roles separated.